# Get rid of space at top of grid item from post date in DOM

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've got a bit of an issue with my CSS in a Wordpress theme I'm working on from scratch.

If I take it out of the DOM flow, this problem space disappears, but then it breaks the layout and won't position properly. The problem element itself is the .post-date class. This needs to be above the image in order to display in the proper position for responsiveness purposes.

[image]

This is introduced from the flow of the document and how It is positioned.

```css
.grid {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
 grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.block {
 display: block;
}

.col {
 grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
 grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 300px);
}

.post-thumb {
 top: 0; /* Doesn't Work without position: absolute, which breaks the whole layout */
}

.post-thumb img {
 background-size: auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 max-height: 40em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 object-fit: cover;
 display: block;
}
.posts .post-date {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 40px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 60%, 100% 100%, 12% 100%, 0 0, 0 0);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 60%, 100% 100%, 12% 100%, 0 0, 0 0);
    float: right;
    transform: translate(1px, 44px);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid row posts">
    <?php while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post(); ?>
     <div class="col">

      <?php
       $perma_cat = get_post_meta($post->ID , '_category_permalink', true);
        if ( $perma_cat != null ) {
         $cat_id = $perma_cat['category'];
         $category = get_category($cat_id);
        } else {
        $categories = get_the_category();
        $category = $categories[0];
        }
        $category_link = get_category_link($category);
        $category_name = $category->name;  
       ?>
      
      <picture class="post-thumb block">
       <p class="post-date bg-darkpurple">
       <?php 
        //echo get_the_date()
         $u_time = get_the_time('U');
         $u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U');
         if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) {
         echo "Last updated ";
         the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
         echo ""; }
         else {echo "Posted "; the_time('F jS, Y');}
       ?></p>
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?></a>
       <a class="post-cat bg-darkpurple" href="<?php echo $category_link ?>"><?php echo $category_name ?></a>
       
      </picture>
      
      <h3>
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
       </a>
      </h3>
      <p class="excerpt">
       <?php the_excerpt(20); ?>
      </p>
      
     </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
   </div>
```

Is there a way to nix that spacing so that there isn't a link to the article in the blank area? I've tried transform:translate(x,x); to no avail, position:absolute DOES work, but breaks the grid layout.

Negative margin simply moves it up, the blank area link is still present.

Thanks for any and all insight!

PS, the CSS isn't optimized at all, this is still in the early stages of development.

Comment: Do you have tried `.block{ display: inline-block;}`

Comment: Yeah, space is still there, and it becomes too small to fill the grid area.

Comment: Did you tried a negative margin/height value for `.post-date` or a `display: none` ?

Comment: Display: none works, but then the date won't display.

A negative margin (On .col) shifts it up, but the area is still a link.

Both are undesirable.

Height also doesn't work. It simply results in it not conforming to the site container.

Ideally, I just want to remove the .post date item from DOM without causing it to break.

Position Absolute fixes this, but then it can not align to the right side of the image.

Comment: Translating it with the Transform property breaks it for responsiveness.

Comment: Tried Height: 0, padding: 5px, 20px, 30px, 40px; But it readds the space with padding.

Comment: Share the URL please. Can you use https://localbyflywheel.com/ if you are on local so that you can transfer it live?